# How to run mypyc generated code without the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, mypyc

I want to write code in Python but still have real-time capable code. This means I cannot use the Python interpreter. Mypyc looks promising for this very specific purpose, even though it is not a goal of the tool, as it is only meant to accelerate Python. Would it be possible to run mypyc generated code without the Python interpreter?

I have tried the following things, without success:

- Compiling `__native.c` with gcc and manually linking it to files it requires, such as `Python.h` (in python installation) and mypyc libraries.
- Opening the .so file in a C program with `dlopen` and importing functions with `dlsym`.

Comment: Did 'mypyc' create a C-source? How did you try to compile it, and what error-message did you get?

Comment: mypyc's main output is a .so file, but in the build directory a file named `__native.c` can be found. This file is difficult to read and has a lot of dependencies which can be found in two places: the first is `Python.h` which is part of CPython and can be found in `/usr/include/python3.9`, the others are libraries from mypyc itself and can be found in the site-packages directory, in my case `/home/<name>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypyc/lib-rt/`. I linked these two directories with `-I`. This results in a lots of `undefined reference to ...`, for instance `PyList_Append`.